# In Clickhouse, how to parse date/datetime in a given format?

Tags: clickhouse

In clickhouse, is there a function can parse date/datetime in a given format, like

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-17 11:37:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH12') FROM TEST_DATETIME_FUNC_1;
**Expected result**: 2022-01-17 11:00:00

Parse or convert related functions, such as: toDateTime64(), parseDateTimeBestEffort() doesn't provide format function; formatDateTime() will get "2022-01-17 11"

Answer (score 3):

These functions convert STRING type to DATETIME type.
Clickhouse does not have a type for time without minutes and seconds.

There is function `toStartOfHour`

```sql
SELECT toStartOfHour(toDateTime('2022-01-17 11:37:00'))

┌─toStartOfHour(toDateTime('2022-01-17 11:37:00'))─┐
│                              2022-01-17 11:00:00 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#tostartofhour

Also check other functions

```
toStartOfDay
toStartOfHour
toStartOfMinute
toStartOfSecond
toStartOfFiveMinute
toStartOfTenMinutes
toStartOfFifteenMinutes
toStartOfInterval(time_or_data, INTERVAL x unit [, time_zone])
toTime
```

Comment: Also the function `toStartOfMonth`  may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, if you have string with other format try to use `parseDateTimeBestEffort` function https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#parsedatetimebesteffort

Answer (score 1):

Function `formatDateTime` can be used to format date time.

```
select event_time, formatDateTime(event_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), now()
```

demo output:

```
2023-06-09 02:40:57.000, 2023-06-09 02:40:57, 2023-06-09 06:16:48.000
```