# toHour and date_trunc functions do not work accurate in clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse, dbeaver

I wanna  split time field to before hour and after hour part and based on the definition of

`date_trunc` i am using this code:

```
date_trunc('hour', time_field)
```

input: 2022-07-31 20:00:23.000
output:  2022-07-31 19:30:00.000

Why this code changes `20:00:23.000` to `19:30:00.000`.

And my second question is about `toHour` .I am using below code :

```
toHour(time_field)
```

input :‍ ‍‍‍‍`2‍022-07-31 19:30:00.000‍‍`
output : `0`
it should be 19 ,why 0?

and when i use:

```
formatDateTime(time_field, '%Y-%m-%d-%H')
```

input : 2015-10-18 21:40:13.000
output : 2015-10-19-01

what's the matter with these functions? do i need to convert the time to another timezone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Clickhouse, how to parse date/datetime in a given format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740482/in-clickhouse-how-to-parse-date-datetime-in-a-given-format)

Comment: @A.Steer No. my problem is why toHour change the House 4 Hour later . should i convert it to another timezone then give to toHour function or not

Comment: did you define the timezone in server's settings (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#server_configuration_parameters-timezone)? Check the result of this query *select * from system.settings where name ilike '%zone%';*,

Comment: @vladimir i don't have access to server like that.i just can read from it

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to my teammates this issue is resolved finally ! I am sharing the answer with the ones who have this issue. i use `dbeaver`. so ,it was a client side issue, I have to set `use_server_time_zone` in `dbeaver` to make it right

---

See https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/604.